# Application_Start() called twice in IIS7.5 hosted MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

After moving all my solutions over to a newly installed machine (which makes me think this is a config issue), I am now having this problem with my MVC 5 web application(s).

When I build my web application (VS 2013), this of course regenerates all the web code and IIS will restart the application on next page load.  However now it seems, when I go to my start/login page, the Application_Start() fires as expected, but when the page is submitted, before the HttpPost method is reached, the entire application seems to start again (Application_Start runs again).  This second start seems to occur before the first Application_End() is called...but regardless of the sequence I have no idea why this is now an issue.

Checking the application shutdown reason in Application_End() I get the notorious vague (and apparently completely undocumented) "BuildManagerChange"...which MSDN gives some ridiculously vague description of.

Does anybody have idea why this would start after loading my development environment onto a new machine.  Both machines are Win7 Pro running IIS7.5, and I believe the IIS config is identical to the old one (though, apparently not??).  The source code/web.config/etc has not changed between machines.

The only documentation I could find on this issue was in regards to using IISExpress, however I am using the standard IIS7.5 installed with Win7 pro.

Edit:  After removing all custom code from the entire startup of the site, and reverting my LoginController back to it's original simple form (no custom code), this still occurs.

Comment: Well, wasting 2 days on this was fun!  But, this was resolved.  Running procmon showed that hash.web was being accessed by mcshield.exe (McAfee AV).  Apparently the live "on access scanner" checks the asp.net cache, and somehow IIS is aware of this and thinks it needs to rebuild the site again.  For some reason McAfee does not check it after this first time so it functions normally after a second build/restart.  I added a scanner exclusion to the c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET folder, and that seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, wasting 2 days on this was fun! But, this was resolved. Running procmon showed that hash.web was being accessed by mcshield.exe (McAfee AV). Apparently the live "on access scanner" checks the asp.net cache, and somehow IIS is aware of this and thinks it needs to rebuild the site again. For some reason McAfee does not check it after this first time so it functions normally after a second build/restart. I added a scanner exclusion to the c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET folder, and that seems to have solved the issue. –

Comment: Thanks for this - only took me 1/2 a day to find this, saved me a day and a half!  This is exactly what my problem was, as soon as the site loaded McAfee would scan it, and for whatever reason, that caused the Application_Start to fire again (without hitting Application_End I might add).

Comment: Thanks, I have mcafee installed as well

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but maybe it'll help someone. For me it was because I accidentally mapped two IIS sites to one directory. This resulted in two IIS background worker tasks and Application Application_Start() being called twice even though the second site was marked as "Stopped" in IIS.